# Finding the largest N integrals in a time series with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have an oscillating time series data in which I need the find the largest integral, i.e the longest duration before the sign changes. For simplicity here is an example:

```
In [166]: df
Out[166]: 
    c   timestamp
0   1           1
1   2           2
2   3           3
3   4           4
4   5           5
5   4           6
6   3           7
7   2           8
8   1           9
9  -1          10
10 -2          11
11 -3          12
12 -1          13
13  1          14
14  2          15
15  3          16
```

Here is how I find the integral now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import tee


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

asign = np.sign(df['c'])
signchange = ((np.roll(asign, 1) - asign) != 0).astype(int)

changes = list(signchange[signchange>0].index)
changes.insert(0, 0)
changes.append(list(df[' timestamp'].index)[-1])


integral_borders = list(pairwise(changes))


integrals = []

for (begin, end) in integral_borders:
    area = np.trapz(df['c'][begin:end])
    integrals.append((area, (begin, end)))

# this gives
# In [67]: integrals
# Out[67]: [(24.0, (0, 9)), (-6.0, (9, 13)), (1.5, (13, 15))]
```

My problem with this approach is that it is computationally expensive.
I would like to improve it, such that I don't have to read the whole data file at once.
Also I think that instead if simple `append` there could be a simple insert sorted, while keeping only a small N integrals.

Can you point out a way to do both things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `groupby`. Doing the pre-processing in pandas:

```
df['change'] = df['c'].shift() * df['c'] < 0
df['group'] = df['change'].cumsum()
```

Returns:

```
    c  timestamp change  group
0   1          1  False      0
1   2          2  False      0
2   3          3  False      0
3   4          4  False      0
4   5          5  False      0
5   4          6  False      0
6   3          7  False      0
7   2          8  False      0
8   1          9  False      0
9  -1         10   True      1
10 -2         11  False      1
11 -3         12  False      1
12 -1         13  False      1
13  1         14   True      2
14  2         15  False      2
15  3         16  False      2
```

Then apply the `np.trapz` function to each group separately:

```
df.groupby('group')['c'].apply(np.trapz)
```

Result:

```
0    24.0
1    -6.0
2     4.0
```

**Edit**: In order to recover the beginning and end of each period, you can use `first` and `last` groupby methods.

```
df.groupby('group')['timestamp'].first()
df.groupby('group')['timestamp'].last()
```

If you want to apply all three functions in one pass, you can use `agg`:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({
    'c': np.trapz,
    'timestamp': ['first', 'last']
})
```

Comment: Amazing! This is so elegant!

Comment: Pandas can be quite elegant. Some call it pandorable ;)

Comment: But the output of the result is only giving me the integrals . I would like to have the start and end of each intgral

Comment: Thanks! when I run the code with agg, I get the following error: `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
`

Comment: Sorry! I left some old code in there, restricting the groupby output to the timestamp column. Now fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127047/discussion-between-oz123-and-ians).

Comment: Hi, I didn't get your response from the chat. But I managed to solve the problem based on the help you gave anyway. Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad I could help! FYI, here is how to drop the top level of the multi-index columns: `integrals.columns = integrals.columns.droplevel(0)`.